Having trouble with composite data type in Postgres
I am trying to test an api call that loads data into my postgres db table via postman. The table includes composite value types, and that seems to be causing an error:{"error":"Composite class ContributorPair is not a dataclass and does not define a composite_values() method; can't get state"}.
I define the composite type in the model like so:
class ContributorPair:
    def __init__(self, full_name, role):
        self.full_name = full_name
        self.role = role

    def __composite_values__(self):
        return self.full_name, self.role

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"ContributorPair(full_name={self.full_name!r}, role={self.role!r})"

I have similar methods for the other composite values(rights and abstract_additions).And then create the schema:
class ETD_Metadata(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'etd_metadata'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    etds_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    title = Column(String, nullable=False)
    author = Column(String, nullable=False)
    institution = Column(String, nullable=True)
    department = Column(String, nullable=True)
    contributors = Column(ARRAY(composite(ContributorPair, 
                             Column('full_name', String), 
                             Column('role', String))), nullable=True)
    year = Column(String, nullable=True)
    degree = Column(String, nullable=True)
    degree_level = Column(String, nullable=True)
    rights = Column(ARRAY(composite(RightsTriple,
                       Column('right_text', String),
                       Column('rights_type', String),
                       Column('identifier', String))), nullable=True)
    keywords = Column(ARRAY(Text), nullable=True)
    abstract = Column(Text, nullable=True)
    abstract_additions = Column(ARRAY(composite(AbstractPair,
                                   Column('abstract_text', String),
                                   Column('abstract_type', String))), nullable=True)
    scanned = Column(Boolean, nullable=True)

I then route the api call with this method:
def add_etd_metadata():
    data = request.get_json()
    db: Session = SessionLocal()
    try:
        new_etd_metadata = ETD_Metadata(
            etds_id=data['etds_id'],
            title=data.get('title'),
            author=data.get('author'),
            institution=data.get('institution'),
            department=data.get('department'),
            contributors=[ContributorPair(c['full_name'], c['role']) for c in data.get('contributors', [])],
            year=data.get('year'),
            degree=data.get('degree'),
            degree_level=data.get('degree_level'),
            rights=[RightsTriple(r['right_text'], r['rights_type'], r['identifier']) for r in data.get('rights', [])],
            keywords=data.get('keywords', []),
            abstract=data.get('abstract'),
            abstract_additions=[AbstractPair(a['abstract_text'], a['abstract_type']) for a in data.get('abstract_additions', [])],
            scanned=data.get('scanned', False)
        )

        db.add(new_etd_metadata)
        db.commit()
        return jsonify({"message": "ETD Metadata added successfully", "id": new_etd_metadata.id}), 201
    except Exception as e:
        db.rollback()
        return jsonify({"error": str(e)}), 500
    finally:
        db.close()

When I test this on postman I get this error regarding composite_values() function, and I'm not sure where I am going wrong in this setup. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Can you do what you want on the psql client? Post that  code here rather than Python, most of us aren't Pythonistas. Once you have it working through the client, then see how it can be "transformed" into Python!

Well, I keep telling people that they should not use composite types in column definitions, because it makes life complicated for no discernible benefit...
